# How to manipulate columns and rows in a 2D array with pointer arithmetic

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, implicit-conversion, pointer-arithmetic

Over the past few days i have made myself familiar with 2D arrays and the pointer arithmetic involved in operating them for example

```
int array[2][2] = {{1,2},{3,4}}, *p = (*a);
// to access the value of the ith element in the array
// you can do *(p+i)
```

That is simple enough but when accessing the elements in a 2D array the array layout in memory is linear i.e it looks like this:

```
[1]  [2]  [3]  [4]
0x4  0x8  0x12 0x16
```

My question is how can one manipulate rows and columns using this way of referencing and accessing arrays in C?

For example i have this program below:

```
#include <stdio.h>                                                              
                                                                                  
  int main(void){                                                                 
                                                                                  
      int a[4][4] = {{1,2,3,4},{5,6,7,8},{1,2,3,4},{5,6,7,333}}, input = 0;       
      int *p = &(*(*a)), i = 0;                                                   
                                                                                  
      for (;p <= ((*a)+15); p++){                                                 
          printf("Enter 4 numbers for array %d\n: ", i);                          
          scanf("%d", &input);                                                    
          *p = input; i++;                                                        
      }                                                                           
                                                                                  
                                                                                  
      return 0;                                                                   
  }
```

I want to input 4 numbers at one time within the array without using brackets and only pointer arithmetic, how would i know when the end of the array has been reached and then to prompt for the next array to be filled out? And how could i process the columns and rows separately?

p.s i have done research on this and the answers i found in stackoverflow dont answer my question sufficiently.

Answer (score 2):

If I have understood you correctly then you need something like the following.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    enum { N = 4 };
    int a[N][N];
    
    for ( int ( *p )[N] = a; p != a + N; ++p )
    {
        printf( "Enter %d numbers for array %td: ", N, p - a );
        for ( int *q = *p; q != *p + N; ++q )
        {
            scanf( "%d", q );
        }
    }
    
    for ( int ( *p )[N] = a; p != a + N; ++p )
    {
        for ( int *q = *p; q != *p + N; ++q )
        {
            printf( "%d ", *q );
        }
        putchar( '\n' );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The program output might look like

```
Enter 4 numbers for array 0: 1 2 3 4
Enter 4 numbers for array 1: 5 6 7 8
Enter 4 numbers for array 2: 9 8 7 6
Enter 4 numbers for array 3: 5 4 3 2
1 2 3 4 
5 6 7 8 
9 8 7 6 
5 4 3 2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a pointer to an array of 4 `int`s:

```
int a[4][4] = {{1,2,3,4},{5,6,7,8},{1,2,3,4},{5,6,7,333}};       
int (*p)[4] = a; 
                                                                                        
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {                             
    printf("Enter 4 numbers for array %d\n: ", i);                          
    scanf("%d %d %d %d", p[0], p[1], p[2], p[3]);                                                    
    p++;                                       
}
```

Comment: Then just replace `scanf("%d %d %d %d", p[0], p[1], p[2], p[3]);` with `for (int *q = *p, j = 0; j < 4; j++) scanf("%d", q++);`